# Hitting time estimates

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, asymptotics

In a number of different contexts, I have wanted to estimate hitting times for a monotonic process $(T_n)$ taking values in the reals (or sometimes a process $(T_n,X_n)$ taking values in $\mathbb R^2$ where the first component is monotonic). I'm assuming the step size is small, and am interested in the first time, $\tau_1$, that $T_n$ exceeds some threshold $a$ (and in the 2d case, possibly the distribution of $X_n$ at this hitting time).

For some concreteness, assume $a=1$, $T_0=0$ and $(T_n)$ is Markov, where the jump size, $T_{n+1}-T_n$ is much smaller than 1. If necessary, we can assume that the jump sizes are i.i.d., although I'd ultimately prefer to have something more flexible where the distribution of $T_{n+1}-T_n$ is in some sense continuously dependent on $T_n$. I would like to obtain reasonably precise information on the distribution of $\tau_1$.

> Is there an established machinery that can address questions of this type?

Here is a specific simple (made up) instance that I would be very interested to see a clean answer to (especially, as indicated above, an answer that might be generalizable away from the i.i.d. jump case): 
Let $T_{n+1}-T_n\sim \exp(\text{Unif}[-2k,-k])$ and $T_0=0$. What can be said about the distribution of $\tau_1$? How does the distribution of $\tau_1$ depend on $k$?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. The distribution of $\tau_1$ is given by the formula $P(\tau_1>n)=P(T_n\le a)$ for all natural $n$. So, the problem reduces to that of the distribution of $T_n$. Already in the iid jump case, there are a million papers on that.

Comment: In the i.i.d. case, this is precisely what [renewal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory) studies. Its extension to the "Markovian" setting (although perhaps slightly different from what you wrote; I would have to check that) is called *Markov renewal theory*; Çinlar wrote a [survey](https://doi.org/10.2307/1426216) of this subject long ago.

Comment: Thanks @IosifPinelis. I think you have understood my question. I agree with your reduction, and this is a helpful observation. Do you know any papers where this is actually used to get explicit about the distribution on $\tau$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas : I think I saw this reduction somewhere long ago, when I was a student. I don't remember where, we almost used no textbooks. Or maybe my memory is mistaken. I think the answer will depend on what properties of the distribution of $\tau_1$ you want to study.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: So I've certainly seen that reduction in other places. I'm not sure why it hadn't occurred to me to use it here. I guess the ideal kind of result that I'm looking for might say something like $\tau\sim 1/\delta + \delta^{-\kappa}N+E$ where $\delta=\mathbb E(T_1-T_0)$, $\kappa<1$ and the `error' term is in some sense of strictly smaller order than $\delta^{-\kappa}$.

Comment: Thanks @MateuszKwaśnicki: The reference to renewal theory is interesting, but I suspect the emphasis might be a little different: I am wanting to look at the effect of the distribution of $T_1-T_0$ on that of $\tau$, while renewal theory is (as far as I can tell) about looking at the number of steps up to a large $t$ - or equivalently replacing $T_1-T_0$ by $(T_1-T_0)/t$ without making any other changes to the distribution?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: I am not an expert, but I would very surprised if there were no quantitative results in renewal theory. I will try searching for some references when I find some spare time.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: that’s very kind of you, but I don’t think I should be asking you to do a literature survey on my behalf!

Comment: I think [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.08672.pdf) by Reinert and Yang begins with an up-to-date discussion of known quantitative bounds on the distribution of $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @MateuszKwaśnicki. This is really the kind of thing I was interested in seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$
Consider the iid case, when $T_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$, where $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are positive iid random variables with, say, $EX_1=\de\to0$, $Var\,X_1=\de^2\si^2$, $E|X_1|^3=\de^3\be<\infty$ (scaling with $\de$) such that 
\begin{equation}
\be\sqrt\de/\si^3\to0,\quad \de\si^2\to0. \tag{0} 
\end{equation}

The simple key observation is that 
\begin{equation}
 P(\tau_1\le n)=P(T_n>1). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Note that $ET_n=n\de$ and $Var\,T_n=n\de^2\si^2$.

So, by Chebyshev's inequality, for any fixed $t\in(0,1)$ and any $n\le(1-t)/\de$,
\begin{equation}
 P(\tau_1\le n)=P(T_n>1)\le\frac{n\de^2\si^2}{(1-n\de)^2}
 \le\frac{(1-t)\de\si^2}{t^2}\to0; 
\end{equation}
similarly, $P(\tau_1\ge n)\to0$ if $n\sim(1+t)/\de$ and hence if $n\gtrsim(1+t)/\de$. 
So, 
\begin{equation}
 \de\tau_1\to1
\end{equation}
in probability and hence 
without loss of generality we need consider only 
\begin{equation}
 n\sim1/\de 
\end{equation}
in (1).

Next, by the Berry--Esseen inequality, 
\begin{equation}
 P(\tau_1\le n)=P(T_n>1)=P\Big(Z>\frac{1-n\de}{\de\si\sqrt n}\Big)+R
 =P\Big(Z\le\frac{n-1/\de}{\si\sqrt n}\Big)+R,
\end{equation}
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
 |R|\le C\frac\be{\si^3\sqrt n}\sim C\frac{\be\sqrt\de}{\si^3}\to0 
\end{equation}
by (0), 
and $C$ is a universal constant. 
Also, assuming $|\frac{n-1/\de}{\si\sqrt n}|=O(1)$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 P\Big(Z\le\frac{n-1/\de}{\si\sqrt n}\Big)
 =P\Big(Z\le\frac{n-1/\de}{\si/\sqrt\de}\Big)+o(1). 
\end{equation}

So, $\tau_1$ is asymptotically normal with asymptotic mean $1/\de$ and asymptotic variance $\si^2/\de$.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is very much in the spirit of what I was hoping for.